# Transfer data to dialog box when clicked

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I would like when clicking on my accordion, the data in this line will go into the form of my dialog box. But I am not receiving any data in the form.

Why is the form not receiving the data?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import moment from 'moment';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import {
  Avatar,
  Box,
  Card,
  Accordion,
  AccordionSummary,
  AccordionDetails,
  Grid,
  SvgIcon,
  InputAdornment,
  CardContent,
  TextField,
  ListItemText,
  ListItem,
  List,
  Checkbox,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TablePagination,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
  makeStyles,
  Button
} from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import getInitials from 'src/utils/getInitials';
import EditProjAdminE from './editProjAdminE';
import AjoutEven from './ajoutEven';
import dataEven from './data';
import SpeedDialTooltipOpen from './speedDialE';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import { Search as SearchIcon } from 'react-feather';
import { Slide } from 'react-slideshow-image';
import axios from "axios";
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  absolute: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  avatar: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

const ProjetAdminE = ({ className, dataEleve, ...rest }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();


  // const [data, setData] = useState(dataEven);
  const [filteredEven, setFilteredEven] = useState([]);
  const [dataSearch, setDataSearch] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  const [selectedeleveIds, setSelectedeleveIds] = useState([]);

  // const dateR = new Date()
  // const dateReel = dateR.setDate(dateR.getDate()+1);

  const handleLimitChange = (event) => {
    setLimit(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePageChange = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/employees")
      .then((res) => {
        setDataSearch(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);


  const suppression = (id) => {

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/evenement/' + id, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    })
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => {
        // setDataSearch(res.data);
        console.log(res)
      })

    alert(JSON.stringify("événement Numéro " + id + " supprimé"))

  }

  // const modification =(id) =>{

  //   fetch('http://localhost:8080/update/' + id, {
  //     method: 'PUT',
  //   })
  //   .then(res => res.text()) 
  //   .then(res => console.log(res))

  //   alert(JSON.stringify("événement Numéro " +id+ " modifié"))

  // }

  // alert(JSON.stringify(index))

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredEven(
      dataSearch.filter((Evenen) =>
        Evenen.descrip_evene.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }, [search, dataSearch]);


  return (
    <Card
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
      {...rest}
    >

      <>
        <Box
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="left"
          style={{ height: 30 }}
        >
          <Typography variant="h3" style={{ margin: 10, color: '#1565C0' }}>
            LISTE DES EVENEMENTS
            </Typography>
        </Box>

        <Box mt={3}>
          <Card>
            <CardContent>
              <Box maxWidth={500}>
                <TextField
                  value={search}
                  onChange={e => {
                    setSearch(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  fullWidth
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <SvgIcon
                          fontSize="small"
                          color="action"
                        >
                          <SearchIcon />
                        </SvgIcon>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    )
                  }}
                  placeholder="Recherchez un évenement"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              </Box>
              {/* <Button
                  color="primary"
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick = {alert(JSON.stringify(dateReel))}
                >
                  Rechercher
              </Button> */}

            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Box>


        <Grid>
          <Grid spacing={1} md={8} xs={12} style={{ margin: 2 }}>
            {filteredEven.map((recherche, index) => (

              <Accordion style={{ marginTop: 30 }} >
                <AccordionSummary
                  expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                  aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                  id="panel1a-header"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: '#DADFD9' }}
                >
                  <Grid container spacing={1} md={12} xs={12} style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                    <Grid item md={2} xs={4}>
                      {recherche.date_even.slice(0, 10)}
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item md={2} xs={2}>
                      {recherche.prix_even}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={2} xs={3}>
                      {recherche.statut}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={3} xs={3}>
                      {recherche.descrip_evene}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={3} xs={8} style={{ marginTop: -10 }}>
                      <IconButton>
                        <EditProjAdminE
                          dataSearch={dataSearch}
                          setDataSearch={setDataSearch}
                          id={recherche.id}
                        />
                      </IconButton>
                      <IconButton
                        onClick={async () => {
                          suppression(recherche.id)
                          window.location.reload(false)
                        }}
                      >
                        <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                      </IconButton>
                      {/* <SpeedDialTooltipOpen/> */}
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>

                  <List>

                    <ListItem>
                      <ListItemText primary={
                        <Typography variant="caption" style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>
                          {recherche.id}
                        </Typography>
                      }
                        secondary="Membre concerné"
                      />
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem>
                      <ListItemText primary={
                        <Typography variant="caption" style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>
                          {recherche.lieu}
                        </Typography>

                      }
                        secondary="Lieu"
                      />
                    </ListItem>


                    <ListItem>
                      <ListItemText primary={
                        <Typography variant="caption" style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>
                          {recherche.heure}
                        </Typography>
                      }
                        secondary="Heure"
                      />
                    </ListItem>
                  </List>

                </AccordionDetails>
              </Accordion>
            ))}
          </Grid>

        </Grid>

        <AjoutEven />
      </>


    </Card>
  );
};

// Results.propTypes = {
//         className: PropTypes.string,
//   dataEleve: PropTypes.array.isRequired
// };

export default ProjetAdminE;
```

editProjetEven.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import moment from 'moment';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import { makeStyles, useTheme, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    Button,
    Grid,
    MenuItem,
    DialogContent,
    DialogActions,
    Dialog,
    IconButton,
    Avatar,
    TextField,
    DialogTitle,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import getInitials from 'src/utils/getInitials';
import CreateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Create';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: 645,
    },
    item: {
        height: 50
    },
    buttonDial: {
        color: "#fff",
    },
    buttonAnnuler: {
        color: "red"
    },
    buttonSave: {
        background: "#558b2f",
        color: "#558b2f",
    }
}));



export default function EditProjAdminE(setDataSearch,dataSearch,data,setData,id,index) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [opens, setOpens] = React.useState(false);

    const handleChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target
        setDataSearch({ ...dataSearch, [name]: value })
    }


    // const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down(645));

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };
    // const handleInputChange = event => {
    //     const { name, value } = event.target
    //     setData({ ...data, [name]: value })
    // }

    // const item = dataSearch.find(id);

    return (
        <div>

            <div display="flex">
                <IconButton onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    <EditIcon fontSize="small" alt="modifier" style={{ color: '#205723' }} />
                </IconButton>
            </div>
            
                <Dialog
                    fullWidth
                    // fullScreen
                    open={open }
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
                    maxWidth = 'md'
                >
                    {/* { index ==="" ? "aucune information": 
                    <> */}
                    <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">Virement</DialogTitle>

                    <DialogContent >
                        <Grid container spacing={1}>

                            <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="dense"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="prix_even"
                                    value={dataSearch.prix_even}
                                    // defaultValue={dataSearch.prix_even}
                                    label="Prix"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                                />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="dense"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="heure"
                                    value={dataSearch.heure}
                                    label="Heure"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                                />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="dense"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="lieu"
                                    value={dataSearch.lieu}
                                    label="Lieu"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                                />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="dense"
                                    type="date"
                                    name="date_even"
                                    value={dataSearch.date_even}
                                    helperText="Date de l'événement"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                                />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="dense"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="descrip_even"
                                    value={dataSearch.descrip_even}
                                    label="Descr de l'événement"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                                />
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item md={4} xs={12}>
                                <TextField
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="dense"
                                    type="text"
                                    name="statut"
                                    value={dataSearch.statut}
                                    label="Statut"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                                />
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>

                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button
                        // onClick={alert(JSON.stringify(dataSearch))}
                        >
                            Modifier
                    </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose} className={classes.buttonAnnuler}>
                            Fermer
                    </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                    {/* </>
                    } */}
                </Dialog>


            </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This site is for **English** language questions only - please respect the rules of the site - thank you

Answer (score 1):

on click I pass the index of the object to the array and send it to a new array that I created

```js
<IconButton onClick={async () => {
    setData({ ...dataSearch[index] })
    handleClickOpen()
 }}
 >
    <EditIcon fontSize="small" alt="modifier" style={{ color: '#205723' }} />
</IconButton>
```

Comment: If my answer did not help, you don't need to upvote or mark it as accepted, but at least in your answer, provide only what solved the problem (instead of pasting the full code) so your question may be useful to others... I noticed that you did as I suggested and added a call to `setData` in the button's `onClick` call, was that enough?

Comment: For the too long answer this is the first time I made a post.
Yes. that solved the problem
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `handleClickOpen` seems to be only opening the dialog box and not invoking `setDataSearch({ ...dataSearch, [name]: value })` which seems to be responsible to add values to the `dataSearch` object that is used in your form fields.

I would personally double check if the *EditProjAdminE* component is receiving the proper `dataSearch` and then later call a similar function to `handleChange` when the open event is triggered.